# ¿Por qué CSS no me aplica bien Flexbox la propiedad Justify-content?

Tags: css, flexbox

Código HTML:

```
<main class="seccion contenedor">
            <h2 class="fw-300 ct">Casas y Depas en Venta</h2>
        <div class="anuncio-contenedor">
            <div class="anuncio">
                <img src="img/anuncio1.jpg" alt="Anuncio Casa en el Lago">
                <div class="contenido-anuncio">
                    <h3>Casa de Lujo en el Lago</h3>
                        <p> Casa en el lago con excelente vista, acabados de lujo a un excelente precio.</p>
                        <p>$3,000,000</p>
                    <a href="#">Ver Propiedad</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="anuncio">
                <img src="img/anuncio2.jpg" alt="Anuncio Casa con Terminados de Lujo">
                <div class="contenido-anuncio">
                    <h3>Casa Terminados de Lujo</h3>
                        <p>Casa con diseño moderno, así como tecnología inteligente y amueblada.</p>
                        <p>$2,000,000</p>
                    <a href="#">Ver Propiedad</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="anuncio">
                <img src="img/anuncio3.jpg" alt="Anuncio Casa con Alberca">
                <div class="contenido-anuncio">
                    <h3>Casa con Alberca</h3>
                        <p>Casa con alberca y acabados de Lujo en la ciudad, excelente oportunidad.</p>
                        <p>3,000,000</p>
                    <a href="#">Ver Propiedad</a>
                    <a href="anuncios.html">Ver todas</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Código CSS:

```
/** Anuncios **/

.anuncio-contenedor{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
}


.anuncio{
    flex-basis: calc(33,3% - 1rem);
    border: 0.1rem solid #B5B5B5;
}
```

Estoy haciendo un curso de programación WEB básico y hago todo lo que hace el profesor en el vídeo, pero simplemente no me queda como a él o CSS no hace funcionar las propiedades de dicho selector...

No me aplica el  justify-content: space-between a los anuncios... ¿Que podría hacer? Quiero crear una separación entre los anuncios para que  el border quede bien...

[image: Página Web donde no me aplica los cambios]

Comment: Necesitas darle un ancho especifico a `.anuncio`, ejemplo, `width: 30%;` y ya ahí vas viendo el espacio que te va quedando y vas ajustando el tamaño que mas se acomode a lo que buscas.

Comment: Si que funciona. Con el ancho actual no lo notas, los anuncios están a un ancho de 1/3 del contendor, por tanto lo van a llenar. Prueba a poner los anuncios a un ancho pequeño, opr ejemplo 300px (que no ocupen toda la pantalla) y veras como justify-content actúa (prueba distintos valores)

Comment: Si tenía que cambiarle el ancho, ¡Muchísimas gracias!